# Gradle subproject dependecies does not work but same dependencies works fine in main gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have been working on multi module gradle project for spring boot devtools. Here is the github repo - [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rahulwagh/springboot)

```
-spring-boot-dev-tools
-src/main
    -java/com/jhooq/springboot/devtools
    -resources
    -spring-boot-dev-tools.gradle ====- subproject gradle 
-.gitignore
-build.gradle ====- main gradle
-gradlew
-gradlew.bat
-settings.gradle
```

This how my build.gradle(main gradle)looks like : -

```
            buildscript {
            ext {
                    springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
                }
                repositories {
                    mavenCentral()
                }
                dependencies {
                    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
                }
                        }
            allprojects {
                group 'com.jhooq'
                version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
            }
            subprojects{
                repositories {
                    mavenCentral()
                }
                apply plugin: 'java'
                apply plugin: 'idea'
                apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
                apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

                sourceCompatibility = 1.8
                targetCompatibility = 1.8

                dependencies {
                    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
                    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
                }
            }
            project(':spring-boot-dev-tools'){

                configurations {
                    developmentOnly
                    runtimeClasspath {
                        extendsFrom developmentOnly
                    }
                }

                dependencies {
                    compile project(':spring-boot-app')
                    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
                    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
                }

            }
```

So as you can see if i put `compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")` inside `project(':spring-boot-dev-tools')` my spring boot application starts on port 8000 and keeps running

But i face issue when i move following gradle scripts inside `spring-boot-dev-tools.gradle`, then my spring boot application starts and shutdown just like normal spring boot application.

```
project(':spring-boot-dev-tools'){

                configurations {
                    developmentOnly
                    runtimeClasspath {
                        extendsFrom developmentOnly
                    }
                }

                dependencies {
                    compile project(':spring-boot-app')
                    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
                    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
                }
```

So if i summarize my issue when i move spring `spring-boot-starter-web` and  `spring-boot-devtools` dependencies inside submodule, spring boot doesn't work/run on port:8000 but instead it starts and shutdown like a normal spring boot application.

Comment: So you try to move some file contents from your big `build.gradle` file to another file? Are you sure the other file is included after you moved the code? Maybe add a simple `println` statement to check.

Comment: yes i tried to move content of the file to another file(sub module gradle file) and yes i checked other file is included after i move the code.

Today i am able to solve the issue and its make me sad because instead of "compile project" i switched to "implementation" and everything seems to works perfectly. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working but still the solution is apparently does not feel good to me. But anyways here is what i did -

1. I moved sub project/module dependency to its own gradle file and removed it from build.gradle(main project gradle)
2. Instead of "compile project" i switched to "implementation"

   ```
           configurations {
               developmentOnly
               runtimeClasspath {
                   extendsFrom developmentOnly
               }
           }

           dependencies {
               implementation {
                   'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
                   ':spring-boot-app'
                   'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

               }
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you have defined main class in every separate Java package?

I recently made a modular monolith example which might help you:
[modular monolith example](https://github.com/carlrobertoh/modular-monolith-example)

Also some tips to consider:

- define a common gradle configuration instead of "allprojects" and "subprojects" keywords. Difference between these two comes down to [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- use keyword **implementation** instead of **compile**. That way your dependencies do not leak into the compile classpath of consumers anymore. Otherwise use keyword **api**

Comment: Thanks carl i switched from compile to implementation and it worked this time. I posted the solution below.